# What anime features robot armor and reference to "Dell Power"

Tags: delpower-x-bakuhatsu

Can anyone identify an anime from a single episode:

I saw this about 5 years ago at a convention, but it looks to have been produced in the 90's.

People wearing robotic armor compete in some kind of fight. It looks like it just takes place outdoors, not in an arena of any kind.

The robotic suits are brightly colored, this is not an overly serious anime.

There is an old scientist type guy who built the suits for at least the main character's team. There is a guy who fights first, and when he is knocked backward he lands on a girl's lunch (a girl he apparently likes).

He notices tears in her eyes and thinks "she really cares for me! she's crying because I was knocked down!", but then we get the real picture, and she is thinking "oh no, my poor lunch!". Throughout the episode she is sulking because of her broken lunch. She keeps saying things like "my lunch...*snif*" etc.

After the guy's fight an energetic girl is up next, presumably fighting the same person the guy was (he lost, I think). They do a cheer and say "We'll beat 'em with Dell Power!".

The whole time I thought the anime was called "Dell Power", but when I looked that up I found nothing at all.

Comment: Can you tell us the convention? Also, random guess, but "All Purpose Cultural Cat-Girl Nuku Nuku"?

Comment: @JavidPack The convention was Anime North, but I can't recall the year. Possibly 2007 or 2008. I don't believe it was Nuku Nuku.

Comment: It doesn't list out the shows they played, but you may find the programming pages from the Anime north website helpful in jogging your memory: [2006](https://web.archive.org/web/20061217234634/http://www.animenorth.com/video_rooms.php), [2007](https://web.archive.org/web/20070921180259/http://www.animenorth.com/video_rooms.php)

Comment: @Etheur thanks, that was one of the first places I checked, and I didn't find anything memory-jogging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't watched the anime personally, however I came across this anime before and the synopsis fits your discription.
I believe the anime you are looking for is: 
 [Delpower X Bakuhatsu Miracle Genki!](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2058/Delpower_X_Bakuhatsu_Miracle_Genki!)

**Synopsis**

> Manami is your typical schoolgirl, despite the odd machines her grandfather is always building. One day, though, an odd evil robot comes to attack Minami's school, and commits the ultimate offense of threatening her friends... and ruining her lunch. Now, she will stop at nothing to return order to the world in her grandpa's newest creation: the mecha Del Power X.

[ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=3362) also describes the loss of her bento:

> Hanegi Manami is a junior high school girl with unusual relatives, to say the least. Her grandfather's passion is building unusual things and has just had his latest concoction delivered to their doorstep. The mecha known as Del Power X. With a driver seat specially designed for Manami, its powers are rivaled by no other. Unfortunately, her grandfather's rival Von Getsueru and a plethora of other people are determined to prove that fact wrong, regardless of who is in the pilot`s seat, Manami must fight for love, pride, and above all else, the loss of her precious bento.

Both describe the "old man" as the grandfather who builds stuff, and also made the mecha in question and the girl being upset about her lost lunch. The obvious reference is, of course, "Delpower" probably because it is homophonic to "Dell power" which would be an understandable association.

Comment: This is it! I can't believe it! Wealth and glory to you! Thank you! I would have never figured out that "Delpower" was supposed to be one word.